# newline character missing in last line of pandas.to_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I use the following code segment to read and store data. Note the `fname.write('\n')` that is required to add a newline character to the last line. Is this a feature or a bug?

At least this does not look very robust to me. Trying to read the data line-by-line by explicitly searching for `\n` will fail at the last line.

```
data = pd.read_csv(file, sep=r'\s+', header=None,
                   names=['2Theta', 'counts', 'sigma'])
.
.
with open('{}/cycle_{:04d}.xye'.format(directory, int(idx)), 'w') as fname:
    fname.write('# ')
    data.to_csv(fname, sep='\t', float_format='%18.12f',
                index=None, header=True,
                cols=['2Theta', 'counts', 'sigma'])
    fname.write('\n')
```

Comment: Trying to read the data line-by-line by explicitly searching for \n isn't the pythonic way. for line in open('name', 'r') is.

Comment: Yes, of course. But I have been bitten by missing newlines on the last line before even with commercial software.